# Daemon context won't run inside function

Tags: python, function, daemon

I'm creating a python bridge to a program. I'm using the pipi daemon module to prevent lockups. 
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/

I basically want to eventually put this in a module for easy reuse and to build a python wrapper.

In testing, if I put the daemon context inside a function it won't work.
If I put it outside the function, it works flawlessly.

```
def createCube():
    prog('create cube/params')

def runFunc(func):
    with daemon.DaemonContext():
        prog = createConnection().command #our port connection system
        func()
        sys.exit()

runFunc(createCube)
```

I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't work inside a function when it works fine outside of it, unless it's looking for a namespace perchance?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the error message? Is the function in a class? Is the class part of a module? How do you call this code in each situation?

Comment: It also looks like the issue could be with our connection system too.

Comment: @jozzas I haven't got error reporting back yet due to the nature of the setup. It's high on my todo list for usability.

The function is not in a class as of yet because I'm just testing out the bridge right now.

Comment: Call context like this to debug: daemon.DaemonContext(stdout = open("./stdout.log","wb"), stderr = open("./stderr.log","wb")) Then you are likely will see a traceback in one those files. But i suspect demonizing - just closes some file descriptors that are needed, and if that is the case you have to change order of execution before demonizing - to open all after demonizing.